# PHP get youtube approxDurationMs with cURL

Tags: php, curl, youtube, explode, milliseconds

I am trying to get youtube videos approxDurationMs. My code is working but after 2 days stopped work.
I want only with method cURL because this method is faster. 
I have a variable with almost 100 URLs.

```
$vidkey = Mage::getModel('core/variable')->loadByCode('yvideoDuration')->getValue('html');
    $forrr = explode("\n",$vidkey);
    $count = count($forrr);
 function curl_get_contents($url)
        {
            $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, trim($url));

            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            return $data;
        }
    for($az = 0; $az < $count; $az++) {
        $new_method = curl_get_contents(''.$forrr[$az]);
        $scrape_ms = explode("approxDurationMs", explode("audioSampleRate", $new_method)[0])[1];
        $strreplace = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', $scrape_ms);
        $mills = $strreplace;
        echo '<span class="sample-video-duration">'.$mills.'</span><br>';
    }
```

Please help.

**UPDATE**
For example: for this URL - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NeQM1c-XCDc
Must return: 310868
And then for each URL.

Comment: What do you mean by "stopped working"? What does it do, or not do? Where does it stop? Do you get error messages?

Comment: I don't get an error message. Only empty spans.

Comment: @GagikKarapetyan what does `$data` return? - with which video you're testing? also, what are the values of `$new_method`, `$scrape_ms` and the other values? - [edit] your question with this information.